# How to prevent code exit during Python 3.6 unit testing

Tags: python, python-3.x

As I write functions and classes with Python 3.6 I try to write unit tests as soon as I am capable. I am writing a simple function that tests whether or not a file exists at a user-specified location that looks like this:

```
import os
import sys
import unittest

def verify_file_existance(file_path, file_name):
    total_name = file_path + file_name
    if os.path.isfile(total_name):
        return
    sys.exit('{}{}{}'.format('FATAL ERROR: ', file_name, 'does not exist'))
```

The unit test for the above function looks like

```
class InputFileTest(unites.TestCase):
    def test_verify_file_existance(self):
        file_name = 'Test.csv'
        file_path = '../../Data/VandV/Input_Reader/'
        verify_file_existance(file_path, file_name)
```

If the file exists at the desired location, the test passes successfully; however, if the file does not exist, the program exits with a *Fatal Warning*.  This is how I want the program to behave during normal operation; however, in unit testing, I want to purposefully be able to place an incorrect path and register that as a successful test, to prove the program does what I want.  In other words during one test case, I don't want the program to exit. Is there a way to do this during unit testing?

Comment: Have you looked into [`assertRaises`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertRaises)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can handle the error gracefully using try/except
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions

```
class InputFileTest(unites.TestCase):
     def test_verify_file_existance(self):
         file_name = 'Test.csv'
         file_path = '../../Data/VandV/Input_Reader/'
         try:
              verify_file_existance(file_path, file_name)
         except:
              print("file not found")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing try except statements:

```
class InputFileTest(unites.TestCase):
    def test_verify_file_existance(self):
        try:
            file_name = 'Test.csv'
            file_path = '../../Data/VandV/Input_Reader/'
            verify_file_existance(file_path, file_name)
        except Exception as e:
            print("\n\aError. Unable to locate File!\nError: {}").format(str(e))
            try:
                exit(0)
            except:
                sys.exit(1)
```